# Passing arguments to cypress request

Tags: typescript, cypress

I have the following method inside my support/index.ts file

```
function testSkipping(channel='US', test:any){
cy.log(test) // will print SkipPaymentTests

    cy.request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: Cypress.env('EndPoint') + 'features',
        headers: {
            'Channel': `${channel}`,
            'Subscription-Key': Cypress.env('sKey'),
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
            if (response?.status === 200) {
                expect(response.body.feature).to.exist;
            cy.log(response.body.featureFlags.test) // will print nothing

                if (response.body.feature.test) {
                    this.skip();
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

I am calling this from my test as follows

```
before(() => {
    cy.testSkipping('US','SkipPaymentTests');
})
```

I need to skip the test, when a the provided value of `test` are set to true. This code is not working. The value of test does not get replaced with `SkipPaymentTests`

the response of the call is

```
{
"SkipPaymentTests":true
}
```

Comment: When you pass this `cy.testSkipping('US','SkipPaymentTests');` can you do `cy.log(test)` and check what is the value you get?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: And how does your response body look like? Please add that. Seems to me, it doesn't have the key `SkipPaymentTests ` because `response.body.featureFlags.test` doesn't print anything.

Comment: the response of the rest call is also stated in the question. the test in response.body.featureFlags.test is also not highlighted on my code editor so it is maybe unknown at this point

Answer (score 2):

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for this:

```js
function testSkipping(channel = 'US', test: any) {
  cy.log(test) // will print SkipPaymentTests

  cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: Cypress.env('EndPoint') + 'features',
    headers: {
      Channel: `${channel}`,
      'Subscription-Key': Cypress.env('sKey'),
    },
  }).then(function (response) {
    if (response?.status === 200) {
      expect(response.body.feature).to.exist
      if (response.body.feature[`${test}`]) {
        this.skip()
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo don't need template literals, using the variable directly in square brackets is enough

```js
if (response.body.feature[test]) {
```